# Can Athena search all object versions in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I've done some reading around whether this possible but I can't find anything concrete.  If my data in S3 is versioned JSON files, can I use Athena to search in all versions of each object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific information about this, but I would say the answer is **no**.

There would be very little need to load data from multiple versions of an object.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is also the conclusion I came to but thought it would be worth asking anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this is not possible and a very sad  fact.

> Athena can only query the latest version of data on a versioned Amazon S3 bucket, and cannot query previous versions of the data.

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html)